# what is the equivalent of SSLOptions in mod_ibm_ssl

Tags: websphere, apache, mod-ssl, ibmhttpserver

I have used mod_ssl and set the `SSLOptions +ExportCertData` in the configuration of httpd which forwards the client certificate information to the JBOSS server behind the web server and it working fine.
   Now I am trying to do the same on IBM - HttpServer and using the mod_ibm_ssl and am not able to find the equivalent of SSLOptions in mod_ibm_ssl .None of the options specified [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/doc/v2047/manual/ibm/en_US/9acdssl.htm) has anything similar. Have anybody faced similar situation. Target is to send the client certificate information received, to the websphere app server from the httpd.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you don't actually need that at all if you're using IHS and the WebSphere plugin? [This article seems to indicate you may only need that option if you're using Apache](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21292700) instead of IHS.

Comment: Thanks dbreaux. Oh ok!!! is there a configuration that needs to be done while generating the plugin-cfg.xml?

Comment: No, if there's a client certificate it's just always available to servlets calling the HTTPServletRequest API's that reference the client cert